# What are introductory elements and how do you identify them?

Tags: grammar

according to ([https://newsroom.unl.edu/announce/snr/3912/22065#:~:text=Introductory%20elements%20consist%20of%20clauses%2C%20phrases%20and%20words,really%20about%2C%20or%20the%20meat%20of%20the%20sentence.](https://newsroom.unl.edu/announce/snr/3912/22065#:%7E:text=Introductory%20elements%20consist%20of%20clauses%2C%20phrases%20and%20words,really%20about%2C%20or%20the%20meat%20of%20the%20sentence.))

it is 'Introductory elements consist of clauses, phrases and words that appear before the main clause of the sentence.'

but what does that mean? does it mean any clauses liek dependent and independent clauses? any phrases and words?

Comment: Do you actually know how to identify the "main clause" in an utterance? Is there something in the *examples* in your link that you don't understand?

Comment: @FumbleFingers it doesn't exactly explain what it is like what is the main clause and what type of clauses phrases of words are these that appear before the main clause?

Comment: Approximately, the "main" clause is the one that ***must*** be present (it's the basis of an utterance, which can optionally be modified by additional clauses). In the first example in your link, that's *the race seemed to go on forever*, which could stand alone as a meaningful thing to say. The second example is a bit more subtle, because *people have a harder time driving* doesn't really make sense without preceding *in the nighttime* (so we know ***harder*** means it's harder to drive at night than in daylight), but it's still much the same thing.

Comment: so how do we know whether it is an Introductory element or not?

Comment: I think probably any clause that starts with a preposition or the infinitive marker ***to*** is NOT a "main clause". An "introductory element" simply means any clause that comes ***before*** the main clause. In the case of your first linked example, we could change the sequence to *People have a harder time driving **in the nighttime*** without making any difference to the meaning. The highlighted text obviously wouldn't be an ***introductory*** clause if we did that, but it's still just the same ***prepositional*** clause (in a different position).

Comment: (Note that in my previous comment, there's no meaningful connection between the words ***position*** and ***preposition***.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'In the nighttime, people have a harder time driving.' isn't 'in the nighttime' necessary for the meaning so it is a part of the main clauses ?

Comment: How does the answer to your question help you learn English?

Comment: I think you may be focusing on something that's not very important. The idea of introductory elements are not a common thing for native speakers to be aware of. In fact, this may be the second time (maybe!) I've heard of them my whole life -- and I do a lot of writing.